# How to download .apk on PC directly?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I have one question, is it possible to download .apk file from Google Play **directly to the PC** (without any ADB or device emulators?)
I have tried this one -> [Evozi App Downloader](https://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/) but I can't download the app that I need. (I want to download it for my research, but I can't do it ), Also I have read about Chrome/FF extension which helps to download apps, but i need to insert my credentials to this extension (GMail for account + device id), and I don't think that is a good idea for safety.

So does anyone have any other ideas about my question?